# Strange Black Background after setMeasuredDimension in Custom ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, android-custom-view, custom-view

I have a library that allows for [**CircularImageView**](https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView) but I have a problem I can't fix.

I add it in my layout this way:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
        android:id="@+id/circularImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/test"
        app:civ_border="true"
        app:civ_border_color="#3f51b5"
        app:civ_border_width="8dp"
        app:civ_shadow="true"
        app:civ_shadow_color="#3f51b5"
        app:civ_shadow_radius="10" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <SeekBar-
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <!-- ... -->

</LinearLayout>
```

On some picture I have a **black background** that appears in the view (On PNG images but `ic_launcher`for example works well):

[image: First]

I can fix the problem when I change the `onMesure` method.

Before:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int width = measureWidth(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = measureHeight(heightMeasureSpec);
    int imageSize = (width < height) ? width : height;
    setMeasuredDimension(imageSize, imageSize);
}
```

After:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int width = measureWidth(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = measureHeight(heightMeasureSpec);
    /*int imageSize = (width < height) ? width : height;
    setMeasuredDimension(imageSize, imageSize);*/
    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}
```

But with this modification my view isn't centered:

[image: second]

**Could someone help me so to fix the black background or find a new way to center my view?**

Comment: did you try to set a transparent background for your `CircularImageView` ?

Comment: @Blackbelt I just tried with `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` but I still have the black background. :(

Comment: can you try setting red as color. Just to understand if the library is ignoring it

Comment: Indeed, black is now red with `android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"`. http://i66.tinypic.com/w6z6lk.png

Comment: @Blackbelt I don't understand where does this background .. Finally it is not related to the extension (JPG or PNG). Also in the preview in edit mode I do not have that background. https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView/issues/31